# Adding multiple jquery datepicker with the same class but different ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am very new to jquery/javascript and I've used a datepicker class to calculate a person's age. It allows users to dynamically add more person, each time a button is clicked.

For multiple dates, I used a dob class, but I'd like to display different ages in each person's age field. First person's age changes when I pick the second person's date of birth.

Here's the code where I'm stuck with:

```
  //date of birth and age picker
  $(".dob").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(value, ui) {
      var today = new Date(),
          dob = new Date(value),
          age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;
          age = document.getElementById('age') = age;              
        $('.age').text(age);

  },
  maxDate: '+0d',
  yearRange: '1920:2017',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
  });
```

and this is the HTML part:
...

```
    <input type="text" name="c_dob[]" id="c_dob" class="form-control input-sm dob" placeholder="Companion Date of Birth`enter code here`" value=""/>

     <input type="text" name="c_age[]" id="age" class="form-control input-sm age" placeholder="Companion Age" value="" />
```

...

Comment: You need a way to group the two together contextually, either by a shared parent element unique to them, or some other manner.  Then you can find that contextual age element, rather than doing the global `$('.age')` lookup

Comment: but the whole purpose of using a class name is to enable a repetition of the same function. 'dob' class allows to pick different dates and displays them properly, but why not age class? I'd like to know how to represent the id value syntactically correct here. Dynamically generated field is giving me troubles to do so.

Comment: Right, but again, you have multiple dob and multiple age.  I assume they are paired together.  In which case you have to have a way to contextualize them so that you can find the age that is related to the dob that is changing.  Otherwise $('.age') is going to find and update them all, not just the one related to the dob that changed.